# Logging out a user after successful change of email from emailed link

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I have a laravel 9 application and i am using the provided authentication that ships with laravel. However when i send a user a link like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/password/reset/320dd955509c9a236f122a700eec80f0daf18ebdef27770f3d2641ea55d74359?email=admin%40example.com
```

i would like to logout the user and redirect the user to the login page. How can i logout the user?

Comment: If you're using session then on this route first clear old session from middlware

Comment: The routes were even generated and aren't accessible on web.php

Comment: It's just a route with route parameters there should be a route something like password/reset/{resetId}

Comment: This is what i have Auth::routes(); and this handles all the authentication routes.

Comment: https://linuxhint.com/laravel-new-authroutes/#:~:text=Auth%3A%3Aroutes()%20is,Routing%2FRouter.php%20instead.   check this link

Comment: I changed the redirectto to `protected $redirectTo = '/logout';` in ResetPasswordController and it works.

Comment: Post your solution in answer and details what required

Comment: Sure. I shall do it.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this will help you

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

.....

Auth::logout();

return redirect()->route('login);
```

or

```
return redirect()->route('somewhere);
```